# I'm having an issue displaying an email template (image) on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, html-email

In my email template, there is a gap under the "verify" image on mobile devices. I need to fix that.

[image]

It looks fine on the desktop view:
[image]

However, there is a gap in the mobile view and when I view it in my Gmail app:

[image]

Here's my code:

```html
<td class="esdev-adapt-off es-m-p10r es-m-p10l" align="left" bgcolor="#F5F5F5" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-top:20px;padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;background-color:#f5f5f5">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="esdev-mso-table" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;width:540px">
    <tr>
      <td class="esdev-mso-td" valign="top" style="padding:0;Margin:0">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" class="es-left" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;float:left">
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:138px">
              <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px">
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" style="height: 340px!important;background-color: #000000;padding:0;Margin:0;font-size:0px"><img src="https://vnyfuf.stripocdn.email/content/guids/CABINET_3724de0fa275fc46223bf8a415b878d5/images/group_11.png" alt style="display:block;border:0;outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;height: 340px!important;"></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td class="esdev-mso-td" valign="top" style="padding:0;Margin:0">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="es-left" align="left" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;float:left">
          <tr>
            <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:303px">
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:#ffffff" role="presentation">
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="Margin:0;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-left:10px">
                    <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:24px;color:#333333;font-size:16px"><strong>Merchant Industry</strong></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" bgcolor="#E7E6E6" style="Margin:0;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-left:10px">
                    <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:24px;color:#333333;font-size:16px"><strong>Suspected Fraud</strong></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="Margin:0;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-left:10px">
                    <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:24px;color:#333333;font-size:16px"><strong>Business Existence</strong></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" bgcolor="#E7E6E6" style="Margin:0;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-left:10px">
                    <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:24px;color:#333333;font-size:16px"><strong>Active Business</strong></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="Margin:0;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-left:10px">
                    <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:24px;color:#333333;font-size:16px"><strong>Demand for Product/Services</strong></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" bgcolor="#E7E6E6" style="Margin:0;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-left:10px">
                    <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:24px;color:#333333;font-size:16px"><strong>Applicant Credibleness</strong></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="Margin:0;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-left:10px">
                    <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:24px;color:#333333;font-size:16px"><strong>Application Narrative</strong></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" bgcolor="#E7E6E6" style="Margin:0;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-left:10px">
                    <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:24px;color:#333333;font-size:16px"><strong>Remittance Availability</strong></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="Margin:0;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-left:10px">
                    <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:24px;color:#333333;font-size:16px"><strong>MCA Payment Histories</strong></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" bgcolor="#E7E6E6" style="Margin:0;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-left:10px">
                    <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:24px;color:#333333;font-size:16px"><strong>Suspected MCA Kiting</strong></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td class="esdev-mso-td" valign="top" style="padding:0;Margin:0">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="es-right" align="right" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;float:right">
          <tr>
            <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:120px">
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:#010101;background-image:url(https://vnyfuf.stripocdn.email/content/guids/CABINET_3724de0fa275fc46223bf8a415b878d5/images/group_9_pdE.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center top"
                bgcolor="#010101" background="https://vnyfuf.stripocdn.email/content/guids/CABINET_3724de0fa275fc46223bf8a415b878d5/images/group_9_pdE.png" role="presentation">
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" style="padding:5px;Margin:0; height: 24px;
                          width: 108px;">
                    <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:24px;color:#ffffff;font-size:16px"><strong>PASS</strong></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" style="height: 24px;
                          width: 108px;padding:5px;Margin:0">
                    <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:24px;color:#ffffff;font-size:16px"><strong>FAIL</strong></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" style="height: 24px;
                          width: 108px;padding:5px;Margin:0">
                    <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:24px;color:#ffffff;font-size:16px"><strong>PASS</strong></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" style="height: 24px;
                          width: 108px;padding:5px;Margin:0">
                    <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:24px;color:#ffffff;font-size:16px"><strong>FAIL</strong></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" style="height: 24px;
                          width: 108px;padding:5px;Margin:0">
                    <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:24px;color:#ffffff;font-size:16px"><strong>PASS</strong></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" style="height: 24px;
                          width: 108px;padding:5px;Margin:0">
                    <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:24px;color:#ffffff;font-size:16px"><strong>FAIL</strong></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" style="height: 24px;
                          width: 108px;padding:5px;Margin:0">
                    <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:24px;color:#ffffff;font-size:16px"><strong>PASS</strong></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" style="height: 24px;
                          width: 108px;padding:5px;Margin:0">
                    <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:24px;color:#ffffff;font-size:16px"><strong>FAIL</strong></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" style="height: 24px;
                          width: 108px;padding:5px;Margin:0">
                    <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:24px;color:#ffffff;font-size:16px"><strong>PASS</strong></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" style="height: 24px;
                          width: 108px;padding:5px;Margin:0">
                    <p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:24px;color:#ffffff;font-size:16px"><strong>FAIL</strong></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
```

Let me know if you have any questions or need any clarification.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the error on my end. Is it possible that you could post all of the code? The only thing I can think of is that your image has a fixed height so maybe the rows are expanding to be larger than the fixed height of the image?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AStombaugh - Here is the whole code https://drive.google.com/file/d/13GFPbetTeFIcbKNWhd96giedj5x9EWQw/view?usp=sharing  Kindly check and let me know, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't been able to reproduce it but my research has suggested that this happens on Android devices sometimes (I have an iPhone). One suggestion I saw was to set the height to `height: 100% !important` and  `max-height: 314px! important;` (314px being your current set height) on the `<img>` tag. Maybe try that and see if it gets you anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Without looking into it too deeply, I suspect this is due to mobile zooming, to fit it into the page (mobiles are around 300-400px wide but this is 550). Therefore, your forced height won't work.

If you have a black background behind it, I suggest that's the best way to overcome it, because it does need to respond to the reduced viewport width, and mobiles will try to automatically fix it by zooming out to fit to the available width.